# How do I obtain the estimate for each level of an interaction term containing a categorical variable in LMER R?

Tags: r, mixed-model, lme4-nlme, interaction, interpretation

I fit a linear mixed effect model to my data with random slopes.

```r
fit = lmer(ouput_measure ~ log(amplitude) * injury + (0 + log(amplitude) | subject), 
           data = df, REML = FALSE)
```

The output summary of this model contains estimates, confidence intervals, and p values for each of the predictors: `(Intercept)`, `amplitude[log]`, `injury[yes]`, `amplitude[log]*injury[yes]`.

I interpret the estimate for `amplitude[log]*injury[yes]` as being the difference in slope of the `output_measure` vs. `amplitude[log]` line between the two levels of the categorical variable `injury` (yes, no).

I would like to obtain the estimate for `amplitude[log]*injury[yes]` and also for `amplitude[log]*injury[no]` rather than only the difference between these two slopes. Is there a way I can do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This isn't really a question about mixed models, but rather the interpretation of the intercept in linear models in general.

Suppose I run:

```r
> levels(iris$Species)
[1] "setosa"     "versicolor" "virginica" 

> summary(lm(Sepal.Length ~ Species, iris))

Call:
lm(formula = Sepal.Length ~ Species, data = iris)

Residuals:
    Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
-1.6880 -0.3285 -0.0060  0.3120  1.3120 

Coefficients:
                  Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)         5.0060     0.0728  68.762  < 2e-16 ***
Speciesversicolor   0.9300     0.1030   9.033 8.77e-16 ***
Speciesvirginica    1.5820     0.1030  15.366  < 2e-16 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 0.5148 on 147 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:  0.6187,    Adjusted R-squared:  0.6135 
F-statistic: 119.3 on 2 and 147 DF,  p-value: < 2.2e-16
```

Here I have an effect of `versicolor` and `virginica`, but not of `setosa`. This is because the `setosa` is taken to be the reference group. Its estimate is `5.0060`, and shown below are the differences from *this* group (i.e. `versicolor` is `5.0060 + 0.9300`, `virginica` is `5.0060 + 1.5820`.

The same goes for your model:

- The intercept is the value of the outcome where `log(amplitude)` is equal to zero and `injury` is equal to `"no"`;
- Adding the estimate for `injuryyes` to the intercept gives you the value of the outcome where `log(amplitude)` is equal to zero and `injury` is equal to `"yes"`;
- The estimate for `log(amplitude)` is the slope for `injuryno`;
- The estimate for `log(amplitude):injuryyes` is the *difference* from the slope for `injuryyes`.

If you prefer a summary where `injuryyes` is in the intercept, you can change the reference group by using `relevel`.

If you really want your model to show a separate estimate for `injuryno` and `injuryyes`, you could technically do that by removing the intercept with `lmer(ouput_measure ~ 0 + log(amplitude) * injury + ...`, but this is [rarely a valid approach](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/7948/176202).

Comment: Thanks so much! I originally plotted the difference estimate, `log(amplitude):injury[yes]`, as a point with error bars indicating the conf int and asterisks indicating p val. However, I think it is more informative if I plot each slope. Is it valid to plot the estimate `log(amplitude)` and plot `log(amplitude):injury[yes] + log(amplitude)` to show the slope for the `injury[no]` group and the `injury[yes]` group, respectively? And the conf int for the `injury[yes]` slope would be the `log(amplitude)` estimate added to the conf int for the `log(amplitude):injury[yes]` estimate?